# Is there any support for adding html tags in tabTitle in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to add a heading and a span text in tabTitle in ionic tabs.

```
  <ion-tabs>
       <ion-tab tabTitle="<h2>Heading</h2><br/><span>This is a span text</span>">
       </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

I have tried like above but it didn't work.But i want like above.

Comment: Try this link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tags-input